# Sequences and bounded injective linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $L:X\to X$ be a bounded linear operator which is one-to-one and not surjective, but with dense range. Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of elements of $X$ such that the sequence $(Lx_n)$ converges to 0. Does it follow that $(x_n)$ converges to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \ell^2$ and $L$ be given by

$$L (y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n , \cdots) = (y_1, y_2/2, \cdots, y_n/n, \cdots).$$

$L$ is bounded, one to one and not surjective (since the inverse $L^{-1}$, if exists, would have to be unbounded, and that would violate bounded inverse theorem) and has dense range (think of $L(n e_n) = e_n$). Note $L(e_n) \to 0$, but $e_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Answer (score 1):

It does not.  As an example, take $X = \ell^2$ and 
$$
L\left[(x(k))_{k \in \Bbb N}\right] = \left(\frac 1k x(k)\right)_{k \in \Bbb N}
$$
The image of $L$ is dense, since it is a subspace containing all sequence that terminate in $0$s.  However, consider the standard basis as a sequence, i.e.
$$
x_n(k) = \begin{cases}
1 & k=n\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
then $Lx_n \to 0$, but $(x_n)$ fails to converge.